# UITableViewCells that are not selectable and don't facilitate uitableview scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableView with cells of 3 different types.
One of the types is as plain as could be

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue
    accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    textLabel?.font = whatever
}
```

the issues are

1. I never arrive into shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath for these cells
2. When you start a touch in any of these 3 rows scrolling of UITableView
   does not work.

Where should I even look to get both issues resolved?

UPD: added assert(cell.selectionStyle != .None) in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it tripped, apparently awakeFromNib was not a good place to set selection style: it got trumped by the cells with different reuse identifier

UPD2: setting cell.selectionStyle to .Blue for them in cellForRowAtIndexPath did not change a thing.

Comment: Did you remember to set the table view delegate and data source? Are they definitely set to the object instance you expect?

Comment: Yes, the remaining cells get shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath invoked

Answer (score 0):

The is utterly idiotic: I was dequeing these 3 as a wrong type for the wrong identifier.
I wonder if I'd better delete the question or leave it.
Not sure what's the utility (if any) considering downvoting.